# Are Scilab and Openeering still active?

Tags: scilab

I have been trying to contact both Scilab.org and Openeering.com for weeks now and get no replies.  They do not respond to request for accounts, web mail, or email.

Are they still in business or have they gone away?

Ron Wensley

Comment: Did you try Scilab.io website? As I understand, you should try contacting Scilab Enterprise, instead of Scilab.org, and maybe you could try calling them: http://scilab.io/contact-us/.

Comment: So I have tried Scilab.io web site...No reply.  Looking at the Openeering site there has been no activity there since 2015.
None of these sites are responding which is disappointing as the Scilab software seems to have a great future.
Perhaps it will be time to go back to Octave but that software has a longer way to go in some regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "They do not respond to request for accounts, web mail, or email."? For Scilab, you do not need any special authorization to create your account to access the set of services (ATOMS, Bugzilla, mailing lists, CodeReview, etc). Just subscribe online (or by mail, for mailing lists), and that's it.